# Extracting data from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and I wanted to do a technical analysis of equities.
Following is the website from which I can get data by defining start and end dates.
http://www.scstrade.com/StockScreening/SS_CompanySnapShotHP.aspx?symbol=LOTCHEM

I am familiar with pandas and numpy. After doing a search on web I came across a library BeautifulSoup which can help extract data. My question is that will above mentioned library would be sufficient enough to extract data from the above mentioned link by defining start and end dates. Or if someone can suggest of any other library or another smart way to extract data.

Comment: You probably can, but it would be better to use an API rather than web scraping.

Comment: looks like that page uses javascript to populate the table with data, meaning you'll need a scraper than can render a fully functional website, not just html. Something like phantomjs or selenium might be what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 options in my opinion:

- use the module `requests` if you need a simple scraping.
- use the `selenium` module in order to simulate actual browser activity with a browser driver. If the page populate the data with `JavaScript`, `selenium` may come in handy.
- another good options is `mechanize`,

For more information about them: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for providing me with such useful insight. Can you comment on which programming language works efficiently and faster when scraping and handling tons of data.

Comment: I am working with all of this module in `python`, which has very satisfying performance in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.